# GUI for image processing in Qt with opencv library

Tags: visual-studio, qt, opencv

I have written the code for image processing that 
opens an RGB image, 
converts it into gray image , 
thresholds into binary image, 
erodes the binary image, 
dilates the eroded image, 
finds the connected component and label it 
in visual studio 2010 with opencv library, but now i have to create a GUI for the steps above like i have to create six pushbuttons in which if i push the first button it should open an image and if i push the second button it should convert it into binary thresholded image etc.

can anyone help me with this? i have implemented the push button to open an image but after that i dont know how to proceed.

thanx

Comment: no i am doing a small project under this.

Comment: Starting D:\qtproject\test\debug\test.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\qtproject\test\debug\test.exe exited with code -1073741515

Comment: I am getting this error everytime i run the program.

Answer (score 0):

try to get hold of the book **OpenCV 2 Computer vision application programming cookbook**...the first chapter deals with Qt GUI and OpenCV..here is the pdf [link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=opencv%20cookbook%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://zenithlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/books/OpenCV_2_Computer_Vision_Application_Programming_Cookbook.pdf&ei=vtjbUIL0K478rAfeyoGAAw&usg=AFQjCNGE_l6oDgAErQEsHH6QLTvBfW1ORw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk)

Comment: i managed to create gui that opens an image when the push button is pressed, but when i tried converting it into grayacale image i am getting error. I am going wrong somewhere. can anyone help me out?

Comment: void MainWindow::grayImage()
{
    cvCvtColor(imagerd,imagegry,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    QImage imageview1= QImage((const unsigned char*)(imagegry->imageData), imagegry->width,imagegry->height,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageview1));
}

Comment: thats my function for gray image

Comment: Starting D:\qtproject\gui\debug\gui.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\qtproject\gui\debug\gui.exe exited with code -1073741515

Comment: i am getting the above error whenever i run my program after adding the grayimage function. I am new to Qt, so i couldnot figure it out myself